# Show data from dropbox to an input form

Tags: php, html

As the title says, I want the the element the user picks from the dropbox to show in the input form so that the user can edit and update the database table.

This is my code so far:

```
    <?php


    if (isset($_POST['oppdatering'])) {

    $tittelinn = $_POST['tittelinn'];
    $tittel = $_POST['tittel'];

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'vikerfjell');
      if ($con) {
        echo "";
        "<br>";
      } else {
        die("Connection failed!");
      }

}


 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Registrere innhold</title>
      <link href="css/visit-vikerfjell-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="container">

        <div class="col six">
          <form action="innhold_registrering.php" method="POST">

            <label for="menyelement">Vennligst velg tittel på innholdet du vil redigere på</label>
            <br>

          <?php
// Dropdown box
          $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'vikerfjell');
          $result = array();

              // $select_db = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['select_db']); // escape the string
              $query = ("SELECT tittel FROM innhold");

              if ($result = $con->query($query)) {
                $select = '<select tittel="select" type="text" name="tittelinn">';
              /* fetch associative array */
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //value kan ikke være lik 0, ellers vil resultatet alltid være 0
          $select.='<option value="'.$row['tittel'].'">'.$row['tittel'].'</option>';
              }

              }

              $select.='</select>';
          echo $select;

              /* free result set */
              $result->free();

          /* close connection */
          $con->close();

          ?>

          <br>
          <br>

              <label for="tittel">Tittel</label>
              <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" name="tittel" value="<?php echo $tittelinn; ?>" class="form-control" required>

              </div>
        <br>
              <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Oppdater">

            </form>

        </div>

      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I may have added a lot of unecessecary code, but I appreciate if you would take time to go through it and give some assistance.

EDIT: This error message shows in the input form:

"
**Notice**:  Undefined variable: tittelinn in **C:\xampp\htdocs\prosjekt\innhold_oppdatering.php** on line **106**
"

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes, sorry! edited the question with the error message

Answer (score 2):

you can check this demo code

```
<?php
$tittelinn = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$tittelinn = isset($_POST['tittelinn']) ? $_POST['tittelinn'] : null;
$tittel = isset($_POST['tittel']) ? $_POST['tittel'] : null;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Registrere innhold</title>
<link href="css/visit-vikerfjell-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="col six">
    <form action="innhold_registrering.php" method="POST">

        <label for="menyelement">Vennligst velg tittel på innholdet du vil redigere på</label>
        <br>
        <select name="tittelinn">
            <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="tittel">Tittel</label>

        <div class="form-group">

            <input type="text" name="tittel" value="<?php echo $tittelinn; ?>" class="form-control" required>

        </div>
        <br>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Oppdater">

      </form>

      </div>

       </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

update your code first like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$tittelinn = isset($_POST['tittelinn']) ? $_POST['tittelinn'] : null;
$tittel = isset($_POST['tittel']) ? $_POST['tittel'] : null;

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'vikerfjell');
if ($con) {
    echo "";
    "<br>";
} else {
    die("Connection failed!");
}

}
```

then update this section

```
 $select = '<select tittel="select"  name="tittelinn">';
            /* fetch associative array */
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //value kan ikke være lik 0, ellers vil resultatet alltid være 0
                $select .= '<option value="' . $row['tittel'] . '">' . $row['tittel'] . '</option>';
            }
```

remove type = 'text' from select . hope your select data correct

Comment: did you run my code in your local server? is it not working?